# Bootstrap tabs changing the position on changing the resolution of system

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

[image: tabs in 1920 resolution,this is how it should be in other resolutions also][image: tabs in1280 resolution]I have a web page that uses bootstrap tabs. But as I change the resolution of the system and tries, the tab is getting repositioned to somewhere else, instead of getting responsive to the viewport's size. How do I make its position in accordance with whatever resolution I choose?

Below is my code snippet:

```
<div class="container" id="toptab" style="position:absolute;top:10px;">
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-12">    
       <ul class="nav nav-tabs">   
          <li id="tab1" class="active">
             <a href="${ctxRoot}/app/user/hours/populate" data-toggle="tab">My Hours</a>
          </li>
          <li id="tab2">
             <a href="${ctxRoot}/app/user/hours/reviewHours" data-toggle="tab">Review Hours</a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am attaching the screenshot of the tabs in 1920 resolution[image] and 1280 resolution.

Comment: can u add a fiddle for the problem

Comment: what happens when you resize the page exactly? Can you make a fiddle or at least a screenshot of what you see?

Answer (score 0):

You are defining a grid cell with this values `col-sm-3 col-md-6 col-lg-12`, that means:

```
- If the screen is small (between 768 and 992px width) use the 25% of the width.
- If the screen is medium (between 992 and 1200) use the 50% of the width
- If the screen is large (>= 1200px) use the whole
```

So, you probably need to change it to:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-3">
```

Have a look at `bootstrap grids` here: [link](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7kkp0zb/)